# Comparing two columns in two different rows

Tags: python, csv, hash-map, bioinformatics

I want to go through each line of the a .csv file and compare to see if the first field of line 1 is the same as first field of next line and so on. If it finds a match then I would like to ignore those two lines that contains the same fields and keep the lines where there is no match.

Here is an example dataset (no_dup.txt):

> ```
> Ac_Gene_ID  M_Gene_ID
> ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010573
> ENSGMOG00000015632  ENSORLG00000010585
> ENSGMOG00000003747  ENSORLG00000006947
> ENSGMOG00000003748  ENSORLG00000004636
> ```

Here is the output that I wanted:

> ```
> Ac_Gene_ID  M_Gene_ID
> ENSGMOG00000003747  ENSORLG00000006947
> ENSGMOG00000003748  ENSORLG00000004636
> ```

Here is my code that works, but I want to see how it can be improved:

```python
import sys

in_file = sys.argv[1]
out_file = sys.argv[2]

entries = {}
entries1 = {}

with open(in_file, 'r') as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        if line.startswith('E'):
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split()
            entry = line[0]
            if entry in entries:
                entries[entry].append(line)
            else:
                entries[entry] = [line]

with open('no_dup_out.txt', 'w') as fh_out:
    for kee, val in entries.iteritems():
        if len(val) == 1:
            fh_out.write("{} \n".format(val))


with open('no_dup_out.txt', 'r') as fh_in2:
    for line in fh_in2:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
        entry = line[1]
        if entry in entries1:
            entries1[entry].append(line)
        else:
            entries1[entry] = [line]

with open(out_file, 'w') as fh_out2:
     for kee, val in entries1.iteritems():
        if len(val) == 1:
            fh_out2.write("{} \n".format(val))
```

The output that I am getting:

> ```
> [["[['ENSGMOG00000003747',", "'ENSORLG00000006947']]"]]     
> [["[['ENSGMOG00000003748',", "'ENSORLG00000004636']]"]]
> ```

Answer (score 3):

This part

```
        if entry in entries:
            entries[entry].append(line)
        else:
            entries[entry] = [line]
```

definitly smells like it could/should be written with [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

This would be for instance `entries.setdefault(entry, []).append(line)`.

---

Avoid to re-assign the same variable again and again as it makes it harder to hard to understand what the variable is supposed to represent.

```
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split()
```

could be written : `splitted_list = line.strip().split()`

---

You are iterating over key ("kee"?)/values of a dictionnary but ignoring the actual key.

The convention is to use `_` as the variable name for throw-away values so you could write : `for _, val in entries.iteritems():`. However, it would probably be better to just iterate over the values using [`itervalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues), [`values`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) or [`viewvalues`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues).

Answer (score 1):

It's odd that you write `no_dup_out.txt`, then immediately read it back in again.  Couldn't you just construct `entries1` from `entries` without doing file I/O?

This code has some weird behaviour, though, that you should be aware of.  Consider the following example:

```
Elephant           apple
Elephant           banana
Eel                apple
```

If you uniquify the data set based on the first column, then by the second column, you, as you have done in your program, you'll obtain the result:

```
Eel                apple
```

However, if you were to uniquify the data set based on the second column, then by the first column, you would obtain instead:

```
Elephant           banana
```

I don't know enough about the motivation behind the code to say whether either of those is the desired outcome.  Or perhaps all three rows should be eliminated?  In any case, the intended behaviour should be thoroughly described in a docstring to avoid misunderstandings.